# Why are Window.Height and Window.Width not exact? (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, window, height, width

I noticed when setting a windows Height and Width (or Min/MaxHeight and Min/MaxWidth in that regard) to a specific value like 800x450 that the window itself can be smaller then the set values. The only time those values are actually accurate is when setting the `WindowStyle` to `None`.

[image]

**MainWindow:**

- Size set in XAML: 800x450
- Actual Size: 786x443

**SecondWindow** (Light Blue one in the Background)

- Size set in XAML: 800x450
- WindowStyle: None
- Actual Size: 800x450

What causes the the window to be smaller than intended? Also is it always a difference of 7px in Height and 14px in Width?

Comment: "that the window itself can be smaller then the set values" - how exactly did you determine that?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Took a screenshot and measured the width and height in px. Try it yourself. When Set to WindowStyle="None" it perfectly matches the width and height set in XAML. When you leave WindowStyle to default it'll be smaller than expected.

Comment: in your measurement, did you include the border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the gap between old, traditional window bounds (location and size) and "extended frame bounds". The latter is actually visible window bounds and can be obtained by [DwmGetWindowAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmgetwindowattribute) function with [DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/ne-dwmapi-dwmwindowattribute#constants). These two bounds match, in the case of WPF, when `WindowStyle=None` and `AllowsTransparency=True`.

As far as I know, the thickness of gap is 7px (left, right, bottom) when monitor DPI is 96 (default, 100%) and increases as monitor DPI increases. You can find a number of tips to deal with this gap by searching the above keywords.